# How do you post an elements value through ajax with jquery? 

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am able to post a string to the PHP file but when I try and select an input field within a form to post the value inside it to the PHP file it doesn't work. Am I selecting the value in the input field correctly?

.js

```
$.post("js/data.php", {postid: form.postid.value},
            function(output){
                $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
            }).fail(function(x,y,z){ 
                $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
            });
```

index.php

```
<div class="post">
<form name="form"><input type="text" name="postid" value="1234" />
</div>
```

If i simply do `{postid: "some text"}` it works fine.

Comment: You never closed the form, but I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<input type="text" name="postid" id="postid" value="1234" />
```

and grab the value by doing

```
value of postid is $("#postid").val() instead form.postid.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  $('input[name="postid"]').val();
```

instead of

```
form.postid.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `form.postid.value`, try `$('[name="postid"]').val()`.

Comment: This worked thanks. I am interested to know why form.postid.value wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

try these.

```
$.post("js/data.php", {postid: document.getElementById("postid").value},
```

or

```
$.post("js/data.php", {postid: $("input[name='postid']")[0].value},
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to send it like this:

```
        $.post("js/data.php", $(this).serialize(),
        function(output){
            $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
        }).fail(function(x,y,z){ 
            $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
        });
```

that way you send all the values from your form to the php and don't have to worry about it anymore